# How to put a breakpoint in a TypeScript file under node_modules when using Webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webstorm

So I am using WebStorm and mapping my Webpack (using Angular2 cli which uses Webpack) directories as you see below.

[image]

I am trying to put a break point in a TypeScript file which is under `node_modules` and been transpiled with webpack, and the ts .map files exist and yet when I put `;debugger;` WebStorm opens up the .js file and not the .ts file...

See source files with map:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't webpack pack all the files into a single file? It would be impossible unless webpack has an option to load the files dynamically like SystemJS does. We use use SystemJS with dynamic loading of JS during development and we can just open the TypeScript file in Chrome dev tools and debug it.

Comment: no you can still debug webpack, and yes used to worked great with systemjs, but now I am moving on ng-cli

Comment: @juan-mendes, isn't that the main purpose of a .map

Comment: @borislemke The OP is showing map files for each separate file, but webpack generates a single packed file, you'd need a mapping from the individual to the packed file also

Answer (score 0):

So found the answer, needed to map ///webpack with ~
see image

[image]

hopefully helps others,

Sean